# I was trying to pair strings together and got this error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, error-handling

I am using a for loop to pair each value to each other but I run to an error when it runs here it is:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nourf\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 385, in get_loc
    return self._range.index(new_key)
ValueError: 403755 is not in range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nourf\PycharmProjects\work\1.0.py", line 75, in <module>
    if str(newdf.loc[fval, "mac"]) == str(newdf.loc[sval, "mac"]):
  File "C:\Users\nourf\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 960, in __getitem__
    return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
  File "C:\Users\nourf\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3622, in _get_value
    row = self.index.get_loc(index)
  File "C:\Users\nourf\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 387, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 403755
```

Could someone please help me figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is `403755` in your dictionary?